# Fetch only column name from the query

Tags: android, sql, sql-server-2005

Want to fetch only column name from the SQL Server. My output is like this:

```
anyType{anyType=ArrayOfAnyType{anyType=Finance; };
anyType=ArrayOfAnyType{anyType=MIS; };
anyType=ArrayOfAnyType{anyType=Purchase; };
anyType=ArrayOfAnyType{anyType=Sales; }; }
```

I want only the names: `Finance`, `MIS`, `Purchase`, `Sales`.

and that value set as a button name dynamically.....

like

```
btn1.setText(String.valueOf(optionArray[i]));
```

Answer (score 1):

What i understand from your question you want to get columnames

So heres the query

```
SELECT * FROM sys.columns WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.yourTableName')
```